# need to write flash game score in XML file

Tags: flash

I am working on a flash game which is a shooting egg game.
I want to export a score(what ever it may be ) to the xml file so that using php developer can take it from there n post it to the wall just like we play games on facebook n it asks you that "Do u want to post your scores?".
The variable of Dynamic text box is **score**.

Comment: Do you want to send the XML to a PHP script?  Or write a local file to the hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past and have sent the score directly to a PHP script eg. `php?name=Trevor&score=103` (make sure you encrypt it though, so people can't 'game' it). The php script then stores it in a small database table if the score is within the top 10 scores.

When the scores are required for display, the PHP/SQL requests the top 10 scores and orders them by score.

Comment: True, but with a big BUT: Even encryption is not going to protect you for very long - all determined 'gamers' need to do is decompile the SWF to find out the encryption method...  If you want your scores to really mean something, you have to implement plausibility checks (log game moves, filter impossible results, report unusually high scores, etc.).